# passing parameters in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, parameters, query-string

I have a `firePie.aspx` page in `c#` which just has a button and when it's clicked do this,

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cadenaValor, valores;
        cadenaValor = "Audi(28%)','BMW(29%)','Mercedes(22%)" ;
        valores = "28,29,22";
        Response.Redirect("pieChart.aspx?values="+cadenaValor+"&valores="+valores);
    }
```

The parameters are strings with comma separated values and I want to pass this values to `piechart.aspx` so a function in `javascript` catch those parameters and print a pie chart, the code of `pieChart.aspx` is:

```
<body>
<canvas id="cvs" width="450" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>        
<form id="frm" method="get" >
        <script type ="text/javascript" >
            var pie1 = new RGraph.Pie('cvs', ['<%=this.Request.QueryString["valores"]%>']);
        pie1.Set('chart.radius', 100);
        pie1.Set('chart.tooltips', ['<%=this.Request.QueryString["values"]%>']);
        pie1.Set('chart.labels', ['<%=this.Request.QueryString["values"]%>']);
        pie1.Set('chart.strokestyle', 'white');
        pie1.Set('chart.linewidth', 5);
        pie1.Set('chart.shadow', true);
        pie1.Set('chart.shadow.blur', 10);
        pie1.Set('chart.shadow.offsetx', 0);
        pie1.Set('chart.shadow.offsety', 0);
        pie1.Set('chart.shadow.color', '#000');
        pie1.Set('chart.text.color', '#999');

        var explode = 20;

        function myExplode (obj)
        {
            window.__pie__ = pie1;

            for (var i=0; i<obj.data.length; ++i) {
                setTimeout('window.__pie__.Explode('+i+',10)', i * 50);
            }
        }

        if (RGraph.isOld()) {
            pie1.Draw();

        } else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') >= 0) {
            RGraph.Effects.Pie.RoundRobin(pie1);

        } else {
            /**
            * The RoundRobin callback initiates the exploding
            */

            RGraph.Effects.Pie.RoundRobin(pie1, null, myExplode);
            RGraph.Effects.Pie.Implode(pie1);
        }
    </script>          

 </form>
</body>
```

`QueryString["valores"]` is not working, if I write the original string, i mean, 28,29,22 in the line `var pie1 = new RGraph.Pie('cvs'...` it works, i think that for any reason `javascript` is not recognizing this values but the `QueryString["values"]` are correctly caught. Can you help me please?

Comment: it should be tagged as c#, aspx...

Answer (score 0):

are you able to catch the value from the querystring?

i have a js function to get value from the querystring:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return(false);
}
```

and you can call the function as `getQueryVariable("valores")` in your case.

See if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove additional quotes in pieChart.aspx

```
<body>
<canvas id="cvs" width="450" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>        
<form id="frm" method="get" >
        <script type ="text/javascript" >
            var pie1 = new RGraph.Pie('cvs', [<%=this.Request.QueryString["valores"]%>]);
    pie1.Set('chart.radius', 100);
    pie1.Set('chart.tooltips', [<%=this.Request.QueryString["values"]%>]);
    pie1.Set('chart.labels', [<%=this.Request.QueryString["values"]%>]);
...
```

and add quotes to code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cadenaValor, valores;
        cadenaValor = "'Audi(28%)','BMW(29%)','Mercedes(22%)'" ; //added here
        valores = "28,29,22"; //No quotes here
        Response.Redirect("pieChart.aspx?values="+cadenaValor+"&valores="+valores);
    }
```